# Elegant way to convert "YYYY-MM" to Date object in Java

Tags: java

What is the best way to convert date in String format "YYYY-MM" to Date object in Java apart from String parsing.

What I tried is below.

```
 String expirationDateArr[] = dateStr.split("-");
```

Then extract month and year to create the Date object.

Comment: A "date" has a day component, so there is no way to create a date from only a month and year.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use `Date`. Since Java 8 we have [time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package which includes [YearMonth](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class. With it your code can be as simple as

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse("2017-10");
```

Comment: Hatsoff!!! Did the trick!!